# reversing text from input file using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to reverse each word from input.txt using c# and linq and display the output text, so far i have a code that inputs the word and reverses it.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq; 

namespace program
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            string output = new string(name.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example input and output? Do you want to reverse every string a file?

Comment: input : I love programming
output : I evol gnimmargorp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to reverse each word in a sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391198/easy-way-to-reverse-each-word-in-a-sentence)

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want to reverse the whole thing or pieces within it, i.e. a string or the word(s) in a string?  If the string is "one two three" would the correct result be "eerht owt eno" or "three two one"?

Comment: You're converting the entire string to an char array.  Try splitting it into an array of strings (words delimited by blanks), then reverse that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string input = "I love programming";
string output = String.Join(" ",
                   input.Split().Select(w => new String(w.Reverse().ToArray())));
// I evol gnimmargorp
```

Reading file is simple:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
```

---

You can also move word reversing into separate method. That will allow you to change [algorithm of string reversing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string) without touching other logic:

```
private static string GetReversedString(string s)
{
    return new String(s.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

And getting reversed output will look like:

```
string output = String.Join(" ", input.Split().Select(GetReversedString));
```

If lines should be preserved:

```
string output = 
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                File.ReadLines().Select(l => 
                       String.Join(" ", l.Split().Select(GetReversedString))));
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter agree, if file has words in lines and lines should be preserved and there is more than one word on each line, then splitting/joining should require additional work

Comment: Thanks, just an extra question, how can i write output to output.txt ?

Comment: @user3215507 use `File.WriteAllText("output.txt", output)`

Answer (score 0):

The reversal code could be refactored in an extension method for `String`; Next, a text file should be opened, the lines splitted to single words and the words mapped reversely to the console.