# C#: Reverse the words in sentence

Tags: c#

Below code if for reverse word in a sentence, the word sequence in the sentence will be same but the word will be reversed

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace reverse_a_string
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a string: ");
                string S = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] sep = S.Split(" ");
                StringBuilder Wrev = new StringBuilder(); //Word reverse
                StringBuilder Srev = new StringBuilder(); //Sentence reverse
                for (int j=0;j<sep.Length;j++)
                {                
                    for (int i = sep[j].Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        Wrev.Append(sep[j][i]);                   
                    }
                    Srev.Append(Wrev);
                    Wrev.Clear();
                    Wrev.Append(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(Srev);
                        
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have unicode characters, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029238/reverse-a-string-with-accent-chars

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to reverse each word in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391198/easy-way-to-reverse-each-word-in-a-sentence)

Comment: and then somebody mentions that Chinese is written without spaces, making the notion of words vs characters rather moot...

Answer (score 6):

For simple text, you can just use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0), [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0), [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Concat%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) and [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Join);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0)

```
var words = Console.ReadLine()
     .Split()
     .Select(x => string.Concat(x.Reverse()));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", words));
```

**Output**

```
Enter a string: asd sdf dfg fgh
dsa fds gfd hgf
```

For complicated Unicode, you will need to be more precise in the grouping of characters. However, you can take advantage of  `GetTextElementEnumerator`

> Returns an enumerator that iterates through the text elements of a
> string.

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToElements(this string source)
{
   var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(source);
   while (enumerator.MoveNext())
      yield return enumerator.GetTextElement();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var words = Console.ReadLine()
   .Split()
   .Select(x => string.Concat(x.ToElements().Reverse()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //method 1
        Console.Write("Enter a string: ");
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] words = sentence.Split(" ");
        StringBuilder destination = new StringBuilder(); //Sentence reverse
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            destination.Append(string.Concat(new string(word.Reverse().ToArray()), " "));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(destination);

        //method 2 but need import System.Linq namespace.
        var reversedWords = string.Join(" ", sentence.Split(' ').Select(x => new String(x.Reverse().ToArray())));
        Console.WriteLine(reversedWords);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from *definition*; assuming that

> **Word** is a non-empty sequence of *letters* and *apostrophes*

we can implement a simple solution with a help of *regular expressions* (and a pinch of *Linq* - `Reverse()`): all we have to do is to `Replace` each word with its `Reverse`d representation.

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  private static string WordReverse(string value) => 
    Regex.Replace(value ?? "", @"[\p{L}_]+", m => string.Concat(m.Value.Reverse()));
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Text (на русском)",
    "Simple test.",
    "Another \"text\": punctuation!"
  };
 
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-30} => {WordReverse(test)}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Text (на русском)              => txeT (ан мокссур)
Simple test.                   => elpmiS tset.
Another "text": punctuation!   => rehtonA "txet": noitautcnup!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Without Using split, Concat and reverse inbuilt method of C# - 

int count = 0;
string s = Console.ReadLine();
char[] ch = s.ToCharArray();
for(int i= ch.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if (ch[i] != ' ')
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else if (ch[i] == ' ')
                {
                    for(int j=i+1; count>0; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(ch[j]);
                        count--;
                    }
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ch[j]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```